# Probability of passing test by choosing answers randomly

Tags: probability

Can anybody help us calculate the **overall probability to pass a multiple choice test by guessing randomly** (minimum score of 60% required) with 20 questions of type A (probability of 0.2 each) and 10 questions of K-Prim where I can't calculate the exact probability.

K-Prim-Questions have 4 answers where you can choose between TRUE and FALSE. If you get 3 out of 4 right, you're given 0.5 points, if you get all of them right, 1 point. 2 or beneath yield 0 points.

Each question (Type A and Kprim) yields 1 point max.

Overall the test gives you 30 points max.

We tried to use Bayes' Theorem but since the K-Type-probabilty is unknown, I can't proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to construct a probability distribution on the 10 K-Prim type questions.  The probability distribution for a single question is $$\begin{align*} p_0 = \Pr[S = 0] &= \sum_{k=0}^2 \binom{4}{k} (0.5)^k (0.5)^{4-k} = \frac{11}{16}, \\ p_1 = \Pr[S = 0.5] &= \binom{4}{3} (0.5)^3 (0.5)^1 = \frac{1}{4}, \\ p_2 = \Pr[S = 1] &= \binom{4}{4} (0.5)^4 (0.5)^0 = \frac{1}{16}. \end{align*} $$  This assumes that for each such question, the choice of True/False is equally likely for each of the four answers, and the each answer is independent, thus the number of correct answers follows a ${\rm Binomial}(4,0.5)$ distribution.

Next, the distribution of the sum of the scores of 10 K-Prim questions can be derived from the multinomial distribution, though it is somewhat tedious to compute:  let $X_0$, $X_1$, $X_2$ be random variables that count the number of $0$-point, $0.5$-point, and $1$-point scores out of the 10 questions.  Then $$\Pr[(X_0, X_1, X_2) = (a,b,c)] = \frac{10!}{a! b! c!} p_0^{a} p_1^b p_2^c.$$  Then we can tabulate the sum; we do this in Mathematica:

```
Flatten[Table[{b/2 + c, PDF[MultinomialDistribution[10, {11/16, 1/4, 1/16}], 
        {10 - b - c, b, c}]}, {b, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10 - b}], 1]

Table[{k, Total[Select[%, #[[1]] == k &]][[2]]}, {k, 0, 10, 1/2}]
```

which gives us the desired probability distribution for these 10 questions.  Call this random variable $K$.  Now, for the remaining 20 questions, the total point count is simple; it is simply $A \sim {\rm Binomial}(20, 0.2)$.  So the probability that the total score is at least $18$ out of $30$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^{20} \Pr[K = k/2]\Pr[A \ge 18 - k/2].$$  Again, we use Mathematica:

```
Sum[%[[k, 2]] (1 - CDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 1/5], 18 - k/2]),
    {k, 1, Length[%]}]
```

This gives us $$\frac{8327843221553613}{2^9 \cdot 10^{20}} \approx 1.62653 \times 10^{-7}.$$  This is so small that it is unlikely that a naive simulation approach will be able to approximate it.

Comment: Agreed, that would take a lot of sampling.  However in terms of answering the practical question of "Is it likely that someone can score highly by chance?" simulation does give that with very limited effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's answering my question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty simulation...

For the 20 multiple choice question choose a right answer from the 5 available at random, the right answer is number 1.

```
fA20[] := Count[RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 20], 1]
```

For the K-Prim type, flip a coin for each of the four answers, add up the number that are correct and score that total according to the rules.

```
fKPrim10[] :=  Total[Table[   Total[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {4}]] /. {4 -> 1, 3 -> 0.5, 2 | 1 -> 0}, {10}]]
```

Run this many times to get a distribution of scores...

```
Histogram[Table[fA20[] + fKPrim10[], {10000}]]
```

Comment: Nice, YMareth, thanks. But instead of a histogram I need an abosulte probability value, and I don't know how to get to that, even if I scripted SPSS to output a hisogram like that. Cheers

Comment: Out of interest what do you want the probability of, the chance of someone scoring a perfect 30?  Second question, why do you want to know; because this is an academic problem you want the actual answer to or you actually are setting this exam and want to know that the chance of a high score by chance is 'low enough'?

Comment: Hi Ymareth, no I'm not setting this exam, despite learning for several days I have the feeling that the exam which I had taken this morning may not come out well. This did not only happen to me, but to most of my fellow students. Having studied a priori probability I tried to calculate it referring to Bayes' Theorem but didn't quite approach this solution. Thanks to everybody contributing to this perfect answers. My main interest was, as mentioned, the OVERALL probability to gain 60% of the max points that let me PASS. Thanks & Cheers, nic